# A compact way to define a geodesic circle of a two sheeted hyperboloid.

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Upon reading up on the [hyperboloid model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid_model) of the hyperbolic space I have found a pretty way of obtaining geodesic line segments on the hyperboloid of two sheets connecting two given points.
I became interested with finding geodesic circles of a given radius **R** and center **(x, y)**..
Browsing through various books and scientific articles I have found a way to do this in [this thesis](https://dc.ewu.edu/theses/240). It takes the circle of given radius **R** around the pole **(0,0,1)** of the hyperboloid and applies to it the same transformation that moves the pole into the given center **(x, y)**.
While this method works I am interested learn if there's another one similar to the way a geodesic is described in the wikipedia page of hyperboloid model.

I am aware that a geodesic line is the non-empty intersection of the hyperboloid and a 2-dimensional subspace containing the origin whereas a geodesic line is the non-empty elliptic intersection of the hyperboloid and a 2-dimensional subspace not containing the origin with slope less than one.
Can such a compact form of the circle be found?

Answer (score 1):

If $B$ denotes the Minkowski bilinear form, the points $P$ on the circle around $Q$ with radius $r$ satisfy $B(P,Q) = \cosh(r)$, which is a linear equation in $P$ and thus defines a plane intersecting the hyperboloid.